# How to scale objects in Unity3D1

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, scale

Currently developing an augmented reality application and I need to change the size of my objects using pinch zoom. Found the code below on the net but it is not working. After adding the script, my object went missing and whenever I pinch it, it just appears and then it goes missing again. And it is very small like only a dot in the screen. What is the possible reason? Thanks!

```
    public static GameObject selectedObject;    
//public GameObject gameobject;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if ( Input.touchCount == 0 )
    {
        Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if ( Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100f ) )
        {
            selectedObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
        }
    }
    if (Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        // Store both touches.
        Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

        // Find the position in the previous frame of each touch.
        Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
        Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

        // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the touches in each frame.
        float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
        float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

        // Find the difference in the distances between each frame.
        float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

        selectedObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(deltaMagnitudeDiff , deltaMagnitudeDiff , deltaMagnitudeDiff);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried dampening the strength of the pinch, by say multiplying a small number like 0.01f with touchDeltaMag?

Comment: uhm, sorry but where should I multiply it in the code?

Comment: Nevermind - my above comment was wrong, I posted a code sample for what I believe the actual issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with setting local scale using a delta is that you aren't changing the scale of the object in the way you believe you are. You're setting the scale to the delta in each axis, which may be a very very small number.

The reason why your object would disappear when the user was not scaling the object was because during that time, the value of `deltaMagnitudeDiff` was 0, so you were scaling your box by a factor of 0 in every direction (which shrinks it to a single point, its location). When a user was scaling the box, the box would only be as large as `deltaMagnitudeDiff`. So, moving your fingers faster would probably make the box appear larger than moving your fasters slowly. Once the user stopped scaling, `deltaMagnitudeDiff` would again be 0, since the position of the user's fingers were not scaling.

You should add your `deltaMagnitudeDiff` to the current local scale of the object.

Here is a modification of the last two lines of your Update() method, including the comment directly above the second to last line:

```
// Find the difference in distances between each frame.
float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

Vector3 newScale = selectedObject.transform.localScale - new Vector3(deltaMagnitudeDiff, deltaMagnitudeDiff, deltaMagnitudeDiff);
selectedObject.transform.localScale = newScale;
```

Final script:

```
public static GameObject selectedObject;
//public GameObject gameobject;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if ( Input.touchCount == 0 )
    {
        Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if ( Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100f ) )
        {
            selectedObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
        }
    }
    if (Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        // Store both touches.
        Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

        // Find the position in the previous frame of each touch.
        Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
        Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

        // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the touches in each frame.
        float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
        float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

        // Find the difference in distances between each frame.
        float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

        Vector3 newScale = selectedObject.transform.localScale - new Vector3(deltaMagnitudeDiff, deltaMagnitudeDiff, deltaMagnitudeDiff);
        selectedObject.transform.localScale = newScale;

    }
}
```

Comment: I was working on it haha, I wanted something out quickly unless that solved your problem just through epiphany while I worked on a code sample.

Comment: should i add the code of before setting the new scale after    if (Input.touchCount == 2)??

Comment: Since you only update the scale if `Input.touchCount == 2`, I wouldn't do that, it would have no effect. Refer to the full script at the bottom

Comment: so i added this code float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

currentScale = currentScale + deltaMagnitudeDiff;
selectedObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(currentScale, currentScale, currentScale); after the Update() function and before the if statements.  IS that correct?

Comment: After the update() function, or inside it? I edited my answer to include your entire script, but with the changes I suggested, you may want to refer to that

Comment: I added an explanation for why the issue was occurring to the second paragraph of the answer as well, for reference.

Comment: It is working now! But my object flips the first time i touch it. It suddenly becomes facing backward

Comment: What's the scale of the object the script is attached to in the Unity editor? Is it uniform for all 3 axes? I'm willing to bet it is -1 for all of them. Make sure the object's scale, for all 3 axes, is `1` since that's what the script assumes the starting scale is.

Comment: myObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (70f, 70f, 70f); that's the scale of the object :(

Comment: oh! should i make the starting scale to 70f too? I am very sorry i am so new to this please bear with me

Comment: Actually, I'm going to update my answer - you should probably just be reading the scale from the object. My mistake - this was a sloppy answer. I'll update it now.

Comment: OK - I updated my answer. Instead of keeping track of the current scale, you can just add the delta to the object's current local scale. This might give you weird results if the scale is non-uniform (i.e. the scale in each axis is different) but I haven't tested it so I'm not entirely sure about that. It *will* work for objects with uniform scale, such as the one you're using.

Comment: it is working fine now :) uhm but why when i do pinch outwards, my object becomes smaller and when i pinch inwards it becomes bigger? A while ago when the current scale is 1, it is not like tha

Comment: Hmm... maybe switch the `+` to a `-` in the line that I added? I updated the snippet. I wasn't sure what the sign of `deltaMagDifference` was going to be for pinching outwards vs pinching inwards. But, on second look, it looks like it'll be negative for zooming in, and positive for zooming out.

Comment: it's all working fine now. i can't thank you enough. thank you for your time and patience with me :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)